# Groups of 3 generator

Tags: combinations

I belong to an association in which has members with different specialties.  I need to generate a group of 3 members to meet monthly for 10 months. Here are the rules below.  Is there a mathematical formula that can accomplish this?

1. Each group of 3 can contain only (1) one person from each specialty. (Law, finance , consultant, banking, etc )
2. Members should not meet with the same person in a group more than once a year. (10 group meetings per year)
3. We have approx 35 members now. But monthly we will be adding new members.  So each time we run this generator it needs to include new members.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a macro in MS ACCESS and created a generator program that you can use for your association.  Here is an example of such a program exported to excel and an image of the same.  If you need the work that I did in Access, let me know your email and i will send it.

[image]
[image]
[image]